# Filter inside filter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to filter some data inside an array of objects which is contained in another array of objects. Here is the sample structure of my data. I need to filter on `categories`.

```
[
    {
    id: 540,
    name:'Makeup kit'
    slug:'makeup-kit',
    status:'publish',
    categories: [
            {
                id: 42, name:'Fashion',slug:'fashion'
            },
            {
                id: 43, name:'Beauty',slug:'beauty'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    id: 541,
    name:'Silicon gloves'
    slug:'silicon-gloves',
    status:'publish',
    categories: [
            {
                id: 44, name:'Health',slug:'health'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    id: 650,
    name:'Julep Mask'
    slug:'julep-mask',
    status:'publish',
    categories: [
            {
                id: 43, name:'Beauty',slug:'beauty'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is how I'm trying

```
beautyProducts=temp1.filter(product=>product.categories.filter(cat=>cat.id===43))
```

but my solution doesn't seem to work.

Comment: have a look at [the MDN docs for Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), especially the bits describing its return value.

Answer (score 19):

`Array#filter()` expects the function you give it to return a truthy or falsy value. Elements for which the function returns a truthy value are kept in the new array, and those that give a falsy value are removed.

You want to keep only elements for which *one of the categories* has an `id` of 43. Using a second filter, then, makes no sense here: it returns an array, and arrays are always truthy; therefore the first filter will always receive an array for each element and all elements are kept in the new array.

Instead of a second filter, you should use `Array#some()` - you want to know if any of the categories have `id===43`, and if none of them do, then you want a *falsy* value so that the product gets excluded from the results.

Simple change:

```
beautyProducts = temp1.filter(product => product.categories.some(cat => cat.id === 43))
```

Here is a working sample:

```js
let temp1 = [{id:540,name:'Makeup kit',slug:'makeup-kit',status:'publish',categories:[{id:42,name:'Fashion',slug:'fashion'},{id:43,name:'Beauty',slug:'beauty'}]},{id:541,name:'Silicon gloves',slug:'silicon-gloves',status:'publish',categories:[{id:44,name:'Health',slug:'health'}]},{id:650,name:'Julep Mask',slug:'julep-mask',status:'publish',categories:[{id:43,name:'Beauty',slug:'beauty'}]}];

let beautyProducts = temp1.filter(product => product.categories.some(cat => cat.id === 43));

console.log(beautyProducts);
```

Comment: Very good, although I have to nitpick: spaces between operators are good things!

Comment: @ggorlen I fully agree, but I just tend to prefer following the style of the asker when showing how they can modify their code

Comment: I think they'll be able to extrapolate and see what you did with the spaces and hopefully crush a habit like that rather than having it reinforced.

Comment: @ggorlen That's a perfectly valid point, I've edited the answer. :)

Comment: Excellent @Klaycon. Never knew it was that easy

Answer (score 3):

Try like this.

```
beautyProducts = temp1.map(({categories, ...others}) => {
   const filteredCategories = categories.filter(cat => cat.id === 43);
   return {
      filteredCategories,
      ...others
   };
}).filter(product => product.categories.length > 0)
```

So first, you should do the inner filter first and map the inner filtered data to the current one and do the main filter after that like above.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let data = [
  {
    id: 540,
    name: 'Makeup kit',
    slug: 'makeup-kit',
    status: 'publish',
    categories: [
      {
        id: 42, name: 'Fashion', slug: 'fashion'
      },
      {
        id: 43, name: 'Beauty', slug: 'beauty'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 541,
    name: 'Silicon gloves',
    slug: 'silicon-gloves',
    status: 'publish',
    categories: [
      {
        id: 44, name: 'Health', slug: 'health'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 650,
    name: 'Julep Mask',
    slug: 'julep-mask',
    status: 'publish',
    categories: [
      {
        id: 43, name: 'Beauty', slug: 'beauty'
      }
    ]
  }
];

let beautyProducts = data.map(product => {
  const categories = product.categories.filter(cat => cat.id === 43);
  if (categories.length) {
    return { ...product, categories };
  }
  return null;
}).filter(p => p);
console.log("Prod:", beautyProducts);
console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");


let beautyProductsTwo = data.filter(product => product.categories.some(cat => cat.id === 43));
console.log("Prod ans two:", beautyProductsTwo);
```